# C++: Crashing of a program using Insertion Sort

Tags: c++, data-structures

I am trying to sort a record of employees. This record consists of entries containing the first name, last name and the age of the employee. The entire program is running fine except for certain input statements ( given as comments in the main function ). The program is as follows:-

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
class cPerson
{
    private:
    string firstname,lastname;
    int age;
    public:
    cPerson(string fn,string ln,int a)      // constructor to input the firstname, lastname and age of the person
    {
        firstname=fn;
        lastname=ln;
        age=a;
    }
    void display()
    {
        cout<<"First Name = "<<firstname<<"\n";
        cout<<"Last Name = "<<lastname<<"\n";
        cout<<"Age = "<<age<<"\n";
    }
    int getAge()
    {
        return age;
    }
    string getLastName()
    {
        return lastname;
    }
};
class cOffice
{
    private:
        vector<cPerson*> v;
        int nElem;                      // counter of number of elements in the vector;
    public:
        cOffice(int max)
        {
            v.resize(max);              // maximum capacity of the vector
            nElem=0;                    
        }
        ~cOffice()
        {
            for(int i=0;i<nElem;i++)
                delete v[i];
        }
        void insertRec(string fn1, string ln1, int a1)      // inserting the record
        {
            v[nElem] = new cPerson(fn1,ln1,a1);
            nElem++;
        }
        void InsertionSort()
        {
            int compare,pivot;
            for(pivot=1;pivot<nElem;pivot++)
            {
                cPerson* temp = v[pivot];
                for(compare=pivot;v[compare-1]->getAge()>temp->getAge();compare--)
                {   
                    v[compare]=v[compare-1];
                }
                v[compare] = temp;
            }
        }
        void display()
        {
            for(int i=0;i<nElem;i++)
                v[i]->display();
        }
};
int main(void)
{
    cOffice obj(10);
    obj.insertRec("Evans", "Patty", 24); 
    obj.insertRec("Adams", "Henry", 63);
    obj.insertRec("Yee", "Tom", 43);
    obj.insertRec("Smith", "Lorraine", 37);
    /*obj.insertRec("Hashimoto", "Sato", 21);                  // cause of the crash
    obj.insertRec("Stimson", "Henry", 29);
    obj.insertRec("Velasquez", "Jose", 72);
    obj.insertRec("Lamarque", "Henry", 54);
    obj.insertRec("Vang", "Minh", 22);
    obj.insertRec("Creswell", "Lucinda", 18);*/  
    obj.display();
    obj.InsertionSort();
    obj.display();
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that the first four input statements are working just fine ( in any order I type them in ). This indicates that my InsertionSort() function is working fine ( is it? ). I want to know what have I done wrong in the program. Thanks for the help.

The corrected InsertionSort function ( as suggested by MM-BB ) is as follow:-

```
void InsertionSort()
            {
                int compare,pivot;
                for(pivot=1;pivot<nElem;pivot++)
                {
                    cPerson* temp = v[pivot];
                    for(compare=pivot;compare>0&&v[compare-1]->getAge()>temp->getAge();compare--)
                    {   
                        v[compare]=v[compare-1];
                    }
                    v[compare] = temp;
                }
            }
```

The correction was the addition of the term `compare>0 &&` before the condition in the the second for statement. This ensured that the `vector v` remained within bounds. Earlier, this was not the case which led to v[-1] which was not defined and hence led to program crash.

Comment: Where does it crash? What's the error? What happens if you look at the core dump or step through in a debugger?

Comment: @Useless could you please tell me how to use core dump in this program ? I have never used this technique. Also, I work on Windows.

Comment: What compiler are you using? VS should show you exact place where the problem is.

Comment: In the visual studio debugger click on the debug menu then click exceptions then "Win32 Exceptions" and make sure access violation is checked. With this checked the debugger will stop at the line that causes the access violation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your function must have `compare > 0`
two way exist that one of them is true

`way 1`

```
void InsertionSort()
{
    int compare,pivot;
    for(pivot=1;pivot<nElem;pivot++)
    {
        cPerson* temp = v[pivot];
        for(compare=pivot; compare > 0 && v[compare-1]->getAge()>temp->getAge();compare--)
        {
            v[compare]=v[compare-1];
        }
        v[compare] = temp;
    }
}
```

`way 2`

```
void InsertionSort()
{
    int compare,pivot;
    for(pivot=1;pivot<nElem;pivot++)
    {
        cPerson* temp = v[pivot];
        for(compare=pivot; v[compare-1]->getAge()>temp->getAge() && compare>0 ;compare--)
        {
            v[compare]=v[compare-1];
        }
        v[compare] = temp;
    }
}
```

`way 1` is true but `way 2` is false
beacuse when `compare == 0` then `v[index-1]` release a problem
and we must first check that `compare > 0`

Comment: I tried this function as well but to no avail. Also, it seems that if I replace i and index with pivot and compare respectively, then I get the function mentioned in the function. The only difference is the while and for loop.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> for(compare=pivot;v[compare-1]->getAge()>temp->getAge();compare--)
> ```

Let's say `pivot` is `1`, `compare` will be `1`. Then you access element `0` in the list `v`. If the age is bigger, you will decrease compare, which makes you access an out of bounds element (`v[-1]`).

Comment: but the value of `compare` is 1 even after the comparing the v[compare-1]->getAge() with temp->getAge(). So, how am I going out of bounds ?

Comment: Yes, compare is still 1 right there. But in the next iteration of the loop after compare--, the value of compare will be 0, and v[compare-1] goes out of bounds.